# How to best migrate one Windows 2008 R2 / SharePoint / Exchange / Terminal Services (All-in-one) into 4 VM's?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, windows-terminal-services, sharepoint-2010

My client has one machine with Windows 2008 R2 and everything on it. By everything I mean AD, DNS, SharePoint 2010 Standard, Exchange 2010 Standard, Terminal Services, Office 2010 and a bunch of additional apps. Everything stands on I7 x 2 and 36gb ram for 7 people total.

I've decided that we should virtualize it and split things into 4 VM's and keep host only with Hyper-V installed to host all the machines.

What problems should I expect? What good advices can you give. My plan is that when i move everything to VM's i will move vm's to safe place and format the host as it has a lot of really bad things happening on it. But this also means that everything will be wiped from current solution so I have to be sure that Exchange etc will work when host gets wiped.

MadBoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tip: Do not wipe host. Turn off. Wait a week. Then wipe ;)

That said, that basically is it. The rest is reinstalls. Do them step by step. Most should validate fast (Office, Terminal, Sharepoint).

Comment: I can't leave it turned off... I can make sure VM's work everything works as planned etc but I only have one server.. so I can't keep both ;-) But i can make some Acronis copy just in case...